# XML Schema Definition Problem

Tags: xml, xsd

What would the corresponding XML Schema Definition look like for the following XML code:

```
<Categories>   
  <Category id="1">One</Category>
  <Category id="2">Two</Category>
  <Category id="3">Three</Category>
</Categories>
```

I just cannot find out how to declare PCData AND the annotation at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

And THATS how it even works with JAXB

```
<xs:complexType name="Cities">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="City" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're referring to when you mention "PCData" and "the annotation".

Here's a very simple schema based on the XML you provided:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Categories">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Category" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element></xs:schema>
```

Comment: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'Category' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

Comment: As you may have noticed, you run into exactly my problem with your declaration....

Comment: I am not allow to put One, Two or Three into the Element Tag (which I referred to as PCData - sorry if that was misleading)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... I updated my schema with a correct version. I pretty much matches what you've come up with below. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it:

```
<xs:complexType name="Cities">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="City" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```